# Getting error on upgrading mysql 8 with grails 2.4.3

Tags: mysql, grails

I am trying to run grails 2.4.3 project with mysql 8.0.36.
Updated driver class and mysql connector as follow
driverClassName = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
`runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.22'`
But getting this error

```
| Error 2024-02-19 14:37:19,993 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR agent.SpringLoadedPreProcessor  - Unexpected problem transforming call sites
Message: Unexpected problem processing bytes for class
    Line | Method
->>  760 | defineClass in java.lang.ClassLoader
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    142 | defineClass in java.security.SecureClassLoader
|    455 | defineClass in java.net.URLClassLoader
|     73 | access$100  in     ''
|    367 | run . . . . in java.net.URLClassLoader$1
|    361 | run         in     ''
|    360 | findClass . in java.net.URLClassLoader
|    424 | loadClass   in java.lang.ClassLoader
|     98 | <clinit> .  in com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver
|    344 | forName     in java.lang.Class
|    266 | run . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1142 | runWorker   in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run         in java.lang.Thread
Caused by IllegalStateException: Entry: 52 18
```

Does anyone had face this issue.

I tried with different version of springloaded and mysql-connector. Still same error.

Comment: i had problem making grails 2.2 work with mysql 8 so ended up upgrading grails to 4. plz make sure mysql 8 and java 7 which i think grails 2 uses are compatible. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/connector-j-versions.html#:~:text=MySQL%20Server%20versions%3A%20Connector%2FJ,for%20compiling%20Connector%2FJ%208.0.